# Finding child widgets using interface type

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

Qt allows you to get a list of child widgets by selecting specific class name:

```
QList<MyWidget*> list = form.findChildren<MyWidget*>();

foreach(MyWidget *w, list) {
    qDebug()<<"Widget name: "<<w->objectName();
}
```

I created a simple interface that should provide same function across different kinds of widgets:

```
class ParametrizedWidget
{
public:
    virtual ~ParametrizedWidget() {}
    virtual void loadProperties() = 0;
};
```

I then added interface to `MyWidget` declaration:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget, public ParametrizedWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void loadProperties() override;
    ...
}
```

But using the code for widget listing doesn't work for my interface:

```
// All parametrized widgets in form
QList<ParametrizedWidget*> list = form.findChildren<ParametrizedWidget*>();

foreach(ParametrizedWidget *w, list) {
    w->loadProperties();
}
```

This throws an error - it appears that `ParametrizedWidget` is not compatible with that code:

```
error: 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'ObjType {aka ParametrizedWidget}'
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The reason is that `ParametrizedWidget` should be a `QObject`. You might want to create a base `QWidget` class with the same interface instead of using multiple inheritance.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to also use `ParametrizedWidget` interface on `QPushButton`? Some `MyQPushButton` class will then have to inherit from `QPushButton` and `ParametrizedWidget` - and both those classes will inherit `QObject`. That's confusing...

Comment: That's not the kind of introspection provided by Qt. `findChildren` works only with `QObject` subclasses. You may instead want to walk over the children list and use `dynamic_cast` instead.

Comment: @peppe I guess I will have to

Comment: @TomášZato, why do not simply derive `ParametrizedWidget` from `QWidget` and have something like: `class MyWidget : public ParametrizedWidget`?

Comment: Didn't you read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063266/finding-child-widgets-using-interface-type?noredirect=1#comment55880731_34063266) @vahancho? I advise you to do so - as I said, I want to use the interface on other classes which already inherit QWidget. Maybe it would be possible through multiple inheritance, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the template argument for [`QObject::findChildren<T>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) must be subclass of [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html).

This means desired subclass must be filtered from the `findChildren` result using [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
QList<QWidget*> list = form.findChildren<QWidget*>();

foreach(QWidget *w, list) {
    if(ParametrizedWidget* parametrized = dynamic_cast<ParametrizedWidget*>(w)) {
        parametrized->loadProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: For an alternative: look at `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` and `Q_INTERFACES`.